# Android app, activity startup lag with viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

So in my main activity, I have a `viewpager` with 4 pages. When starting the activity I have a async task that reads numerous files with a splash screen and `progressbar`, but then when its done and I start the view pager activity, due to the size of each fragment there is noticeable lag time when transitioning.

The only work i'm doing on the main thread is UI initializing. When benchmarking its the following takes place in order:

```
MainActivity.onCreate 23ms
Fragment1.onCreateView 73ms
Fragment2.onCreateView 40ms
Fragment3.onCreateView 12ms
Fragment4.onCreateView 119ms
```

Those are all on the main thread, so it adds up to about 300+ ms lag time, which is enough to ruin the smooth transition animation.

Here is the method profiling output during startup

[image: ddms]
( https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbnDC.png )

I see none of my own methods or classes taking up any significant time, everything is by the system such as `TextView<init>` and `MessageQueue.next`..

Posting all my code seems unnecessary as its long, and all work is UI setup, setting `textviews`, `progressbars`. There is one class the I use on all my fragments to dynamically manage vertical lists within `scrollview`:

```
public class NestedListView extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final int ID_NO_DIV = -1;

    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

    private OnViewListener mListener;
    private int mChildResId, mDivId;
    private boolean mListenForClick = true;

    public interface OnViewListener {
        public void onUpdateView(View view, int position, boolean initialCall);

        public void onViewClick(View view);
    }

    public NestedListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NestedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public void setNoClickListener() {
        mListenForClick = false;
    }


    public void createViews(int viewId, int divId, int count, OnViewListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mChildResId = viewId;
        mDivId = divId;

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            View view = createView(viewId, inflater);
            mListener.onUpdateView(view, i, true);
            addView(view);
        }

        setFooterDiv(INVISIBLE);
    }

    private View createView(int rid, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(rid, this, false);
        view.setId(genViewId());
        if (mListenForClick)
            view.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    private static int genViewId() {
        for (;;) {
            final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
            // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
            int newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    private void setFooterDiv(int visibility) {
        int count = getChildCount();
        if (mDivId != ID_NO_DIV && count > 0)
            getChildAt(count - 1).findViewById(mDivId).setVisibility(visibility);
    }

    public void update() {
        update(getChildCount());
    }

    public void update(int size) {
        setFooterDiv(VISIBLE);

        // resize to size
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        if (childCount > size) {
            // shrink
            for (int i = childCount - 1; i >= size; --i)
                removeViewAt(i);
            childCount = size;
            setFooterDiv(INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if (childCount < size) {
            // grow
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            for (int i = childCount; i < size; ++i) {
                View view = createView(mChildResId, inflater);
                mListener.onUpdateView(view, i, true);
                addView(view);
            }
            setFooterDiv(INVISIBLE);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i)
            mListener.onUpdateView(getChildAt(i), i, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mListener.onViewClick(view);
    }
```

This is used like a non scrolling list view, nested in scroll views with other elements. The reason being I want the whole page to scroll, not the list.

In each fragment I call

```
nestedListView.createViews( 
    <item layout id>, 
    <id of child divider>, 
    <number of children to create>,
    callbackListener);
```

and in each fragment, the `callback.updateView` will initialize each child view.

I'm thinking the lag is due to this class because the fragment 1 and 4 have the longest lists with this class (which takes the longest), and the child views contain more complex child views.

Is there anyway this class can be optimized? I was under the impression that you cannot inflate views in a background thread?

I was considering doing `findViewById` references in background thread, but according to ddms `findViewById` calls take < %0.2 exclusive time.

So any advice for improving startup time of this activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a work around for the transition lag, but Zygoteinit made some good points on optimizing, none seemed to work well enough.

In my main activity I was using a ViewAnimator and calling addView() and showNext() in the beginning of my transition method.

If you call

```
addView(...);
mViewAnimator.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { mViewAnimator.showNext(); }
};
```

it will do the transition after the fragments are initialized in the message queue, giving a nice smooth transition.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things off the top of my head:

- Use `AsyncTask`s to perform the file reading operations and call `setAdapter()` on your `ViewPager` in the `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`. This should improve the UI performance.
- Test your app for performance with both `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. One of them will perform better in your situation.
- I don't think you can call `findViewById()` from another thread. That's a UI operation, and all UI operations have to be performed on the main thread.
- If you have the time, try creating your view hierarchies with the
  default views instead of the custom views. The framework classes are
  internally optimized for performance.

Comment: I'm already calling setAdapter from onPostExecute(), but I will try using FragmentStatePagerAdapter and see if it helps thank you! Also fwiw I've tested findViewById() in doInBackground() and it does work

Comment: FragmentStatePagerAdapter worked for me after the first access of the ViewPager.